# circular replication alternative

Tags: database

I have to four servers located in two datacenters. DC1 <= SERVERS A & B, DC2 <= SERVERS C & D.

I need all the four servers to be a mirror of each other. I have a load balancer configured to route request depending on request overload.

For the moment circular replication sound like the best choice out there. I know the pros and cons of this replication. I would like to know if there is an alternative way of doing this.

I have already create failover scripts to manage when a node goes down and shrining the replication circule is required and the script is working.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An acceptable alternative to circlar replication is a cluster.

However clusers might not suit everyone as if a any of the nodes fails to carryout a query, the query does not get commited. (Scarry ain it?)

In the end I went with circular replication and wrote a script to maintain it. If a node fails the circle shrinks automaically. The same script also introduces new/failed nodes again to the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Maria DB now supports the global transaction id. This will simplify circular replication. We will be able to switch masters without the need to worry about replication position.

For more information read the article below

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/global-transaction-id/